# How to calculate relative risk in R?

Tags: r

How to calculate relative risk in R?

In input i have

```
names(DS)
Tab<-table(DS[,5],DS[,11],DS[,3])

      No Yes
  No   4  16
  Yes  40 168
```

I am new in R programming language...

Comment: Please provide us with a sample of `DS` and the desired result

Answer (score 25):

This is a fairly straightforward calculation; the relative risk is just `(pos1/total1)/(pos2/total2)` where `pos1` is the number of cases in the first group, `pos2` in the second group, and the `total` variables are the group totals

However, you're probably interested in the `epitab` function of the `epitools` package:

```
## maybe:
##   install.packages("epitools")
library("epitools")
```

See `?epicalc` for input formats, but this should work for your example:

```
tab <- matrix(c(4,16,40,168),byrow=TRUE,nrow=2)
epitab(tab,method="riskratio")
## $tab
##           Outcome
## Predictor  Disease1        p0 Disease2        p1 riskratio     lower    upper
##   Exposed1        4 0.2000000       16 0.8000000  1.000000        NA       NA
##   Exposed2       40 0.1923077      168 0.8076923  1.009615 0.8030206 1.269361
##           Outcome
## Predictor  p.value
##   Exposed1      NA
##   Exposed2       1
```

You should of course double-check that the results make sense; e.g. `p0` is 4/20=0.2 for the first group, 40/208=0.192 for the second group.  The risk ratio is ((16/20)/(168/208))=0.8/0.8076=1.009.

Comment: it answered mine!