# Relative Risk Ratio with Confidence Intervals for multiple rows of data in R

Tags: r

Is there an efficient way in R to calculate Relative Risk and 95% CI for multiple rows of data.

Data

[image]

or

```
test <- data.frame(Class = c("Grade 1", "Grade 2", "Grade 3"),
Male = c(39815, 0, 39815),
Pass_m = c(7743, 0, 4993),
Pct_male = c(19, 0, 12),
Female = c(26462, 0, 26462),
Pass_f = c(3929, 0, 2530),
Pct_female = c(14, 0, 9))
```

Currently, my approach has been to do one set at a time.

```
riskratio.wald(table(Pass_m,Pass_f))
```

This is painstakingly inefficient for more than 500 rows of data.

I have over 500 rows of data and would appreciate if anyone could provide an efficient way to solve this issue.

Also, Is the following calculation and interpretation correct:

risk = number of males pass by the population totals in each
group.

relative risk=risk of one group/risk of other group.

For first row, we can say that relative risk 19/14 = 1.36
Males are 1.36 times more likely to pass in Grade 1 compared to female(RR=1.36).

Is the calculation and interpretation correct?

Comment: Can you (1) please post your data in a text-based format (i.e. just the first few rows (`head()`) should be fine, but use `dput()` or cut-and-paste text into a code block); (2) please tell us what you've tried so far? Do you have a method for computing RR and 95% CI for a *single* row of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This free excel calculator does the trick, albeit manual. Wish someone make a R-package/Shiny app using this.
https://www.scalestatistics.com/relative-risk.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for ‘apply’. It transfers each margin element (1 for rows) successively to the function.

```
 apply( test[ , c(3,6)],  1, riskratio.Wald)
```

This of course is assuming that riskratio.Wald returns a single value. Since you didn’t say what package it’s from, that’s my hope, but you could improve the question be being more complete.

Comment: Looks like it returns a list so if you just want RRs, then write a helper function to extract the first element of the ‘measure’ elements.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This doesn't quite work for me because this the package assumes the first two rows are Yes and No for the same exposure. Whereas, in my case each row has only yes/pass values and the No/fail value is not listed.

Comment: You appear to be saying that your data is different than your example. Please edit your example so it has the same structure as your data.

Comment: Thanks for responding. What I meant is the proposed solution is for a different data structure. I need a solution for the example data that I have presented above.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? And see here is a very good answer of Ben Bolker
[How to calculate relative risk in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27593381/how-to-calculate-relative-risk-in-r)

```
epitab(as.matrix(test[ , c(3,6)]),method="riskratio")
```

Output:

```
$tab
     Pass_m        p0 Pass_f        p1 riskratio     lower    upper  p.value
[1,]   7743 0.6633825   3929 0.3366175 1.0000000        NA       NA       NA
[2,]      0       NaN      0       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN 1.000000
[3,]   4993 0.6636980   2530 0.3363020 0.9990626 0.9592189 1.040561 0.975038

$measure
[1] "wald"

$conf.level
[1] 0.95

$pvalue
[1] "fisher.exact"
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This doesn't quite work for me because this the package assumes the first two rows are Yes and No for the same exposure. Whereas, in my case each row has only yes/pass values and the No/fail value is not listed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the epitools package if doing a simple risk ratio calculation with only 2 variables but if you intend to throw multiple variables in your regression model then you probably need a log-binomial regression which can be achieved using the glm function.

```
#this builds the log-binomial model and saves in variable rrmodel
rrmodel <- glm(dependent_var ~ pred1 + pred2 ... +pred_n, dataset, family=binomial(log)) 

rrsumm <- summary(rrmodel) #this displays the estimates in the log scale
```

remember to exponentiate to get the risk ratio. Here is a sample code for returning your Risk ratio, the lower and upper confidence bounds, and p-value:

```
cbind(
    RiskRatio=exp(rrsumm$coefficients[, 1]),
    LCB=exp(rrsumm$coefficients[, 1]-1.96*rrsumm$coefficients[, 2]),
    UCB=exp(rrsumm$coefficients[, 1]+1.96*rrsumm$coefficients[, 2]),
    pvalue=rrsumm$coefficients[, 4]
)
```

Comment: Doesn't this give you odds ratio rather than risk ratio?

Comment: Hi @Bedui the default family binomial (Logit) will give you an Odds ratio, but the Log Binomial will give you a relative risk. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @sunday-ikpe, that's great I didnt know that. Thank you a lot for clarifying.